# How to exclude hidden files in recursive chmod?

Tags: linux, chmod, recursive

I am having to do `chmod -R 755 some_dir` where 'some_dir' contains '.git' folders. Is there any way I can exclude hidden files and folder when doing recursive chmod?

Note: chmoding .git folder is throwing the following error

```
some_dir/.git/objects/pack/pack-dd149b11c4e5d205e3022836d49a972684de8daa.idx': Operation not permitted
```

I don't really need to chmod .git folders but unfortunately I can't remove them also in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not with `chmod` alone. You'll need to use `find`:

```
find some_dir -name '.?*' -prune -o -exec chmod 755 {} +
```

Or with `zsh` (or `ksh93 -G`, or with `tcsh` after `set globstar`) globbing:

```
chmod 755 -- some_dir some_dir/**/*
```

(you can also do that with `fish` or `bash -O globstar`, but beware that `bash` versions prior to 4.3 and `fish` follow symlinks when descending directories. It was partly fixed in bash 4.3 in that you'd still get the files in symlinks to directories but not anymore in subdirs of those as in 4.2, and fully fixed in 5.0)

Are you sure you want to make all the files executable though?

Comment: I am modifying an existing script and till I could figure out why they are doing the chmod in the first place this will have to do :)

Answer (score 0):

Tried with Below command and it worked fine

```
find path| sed -n '/^\.\/\./!p'|awk '{print "chmod -R" " "  "755" " " $1}'|sh
```

Answer (score -1):

```
find /Your/Folder -type d -regextype posix-extended -regex ^[^\.].*$ -exec chmod -R 755 {}
```

`^[^\.]` : will exclude all file names beginning with a dot.

Comment: `[` and `*` need quoted for the shell, `.` doesn't. That will always match anyway since `-regex` matches the whole path, not the file name, and the whole path starts with `/Your/Folder`, not a dot.